# shell script - redirect all data from stdout to /dev/null

Tags: linux, bash, shell, travis-ci, linux-from-scratch

i use travis-ci to build linux from scratch version 7.8. during build, travis-ci throw error because log file large than 4 mega bytes. you can see at [lfs-auto, build #15](https://travis-ci.org/kevin-leptons/lfs-auto/builds/122036437)

now, i want to **redirect all data from stdout to /dev/null** to reduce size of log file. in normal way, people use redirect operation for each command as **dev/null**. but that way make shell script become too long and hard to read

any body have idea to solve that problems ?

---

problem are solved!. thank to every body has comments

i pick up solution **exec > /dev/null** because that command redirect **all** output from std to /dev/null without other operations. in this case, **exec > /dev/null** are simple, easy to edit than **script-file > /dev/null** or **{ command, ... } > /dev/null**

---

solve question duplicate

with some comments, this question have content same as [How do I redirect the output of an entire shell script within the script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314675/how-do-i-redirect-the-output-of-an-entire-shell-script-within-the-script-itself) and [how to redirect output of multiple commands to one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355264/how-to-redirect-output-of-multiple-commands-to-one-file)

i am recognize that my question same as [How do I redirect the output of an entire shell script within the script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314675/how-do-i-redirect-the-output-of-an-entire-shell-script-within-the-script-itself), but my question are more clear, shorter

i need more comments to solve duplicate problems in two case

- merge this question with other question and delete this question
- delete this question and do nothing
- do nothing

Comment: Is `./your-script > /dev/null` not short enough? Or I did not understand your question.

Comment: See: [After using `exec 1>file`, how can I stop this redirection of the STDOUT to file and restore the normal operation of STDOUT?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25474854/3776858). Insert in your script `exec >/dev/null`.

Comment: An alternative candidate for duplicate question is [How to redirect output of multiple commands to one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355264/); another is [How do I redirect the output of an entire shell script within the script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314675/).  There are probably others.  There's no immediate need to change the duplicate chosen.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Bash [Command Grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping)

While there's more than one way to achieve your goals, I'd suggest editing your build script to group commands. Wrapping a group of commands in curly brackets allows you to redirect all commands in the list to the same place. For example:

```
{
    echo foo
    echo bar
    echo baz
} > /dev/null
```

While not technically identical, from a pragmatic standpoint this will provide similar results to redirecting each command separately to */dev/null*.

Comment: this solution is working. and i am still collect/try solutions